# Unable to retrieve actual Width

Tags: wpf, width, converters

I am having one list view

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           Margin="{Binding ElementName=BorderContainer, Path=Margin}"
            FontSize="{DynamicResource PlaceHolderFontSize}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListItemContainerStyle}"
            Foreground="Black"
            >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource BorderlessHeader}">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Backup Date/Time" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource BlueHeader}" 
                                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Converter={StaticResource ColumnWidth},ConverterParameter=221}">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" ToolTip="{Binding Date}" FontSize="{DynamicResource ContentFontSize}" Style="{StaticResource GridColumText}"  />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

As mentioned in the code am calculating the header width using converter. and inside my converter am using like below

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type target Type, object parameter, Culture Info culture)
    {
        ListView listview = value as ListView;
        double width = listview.ActualWidth;
```

but the listview.actualwidth is always giving "0" as result. Why this is happening? any ideas?

Comment: Wy don't you declare `x:Name="listView"` and use `Binding ElementName="listView", Path="ActualWidth"`?

Comment: actually am doing some other calculations after finding the width.like below   GridView gridView = listview.View as GridView;
            width = width / gridView.Columns.Count; . i need to set this value to my column header

Comment: I think your problem is, that when the `ListView` is generated the `ActualWidth`is 0. When all `Columns` are generated, then the `ActualWidth` is > 0. But the `Binding` won't get updated anymore. If you bind to the `ActualWidth` directly, then the `Binding` gets updated everytime, the value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this is happening?

Probably because the `ListView` actually has an actual width of 0 by the time the `Convert` method gets invoked.

> any ideas?

You could use a `MultiBinding` and an `IMultiValueConverter` that binds to both the `ListView` itself and its `ActualWidth` property:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Last Backup Date/Time" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource BlueHeader}">
    <GridViewColumn.Width>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColumnWidth}" ConverterParameter="221">
            <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}" />
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </GridViewColumn.Width>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" ToolTip="{Binding Date}" FontSize="{DynamicResource ContentFontSize}" Style="{StaticResource GridColumText}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

---

```
public class ColumnWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ListView listview = values[0] as ListView;
        double width = listview.ActualWidth;
        if (width == 0)
            return (double)parameter;

        //...
        return 100.0;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then the converter should be invoked whenever the ActualWidth property is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have for example **4** `Columns`, you can try the following:

#### XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ColumnWidthConverter},ConverterParameter=4}">

            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

#### Converter

```
public class ColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int columns;
        if (int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out columns))
        {
            double width;
            if (columns > 0 && double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out width))
            {
                return width / columns;
            }
        }
        return 100.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want to be more *dynamic*, you can write a `Behavior` and attach it to the `ListView`. There you can dynamic calculate the values based on the `Columns` count.

Comment: I am getting the value as 0 only. It doesn't gives its actual width.